# how to enter a document using terminal

Tags: 14.04

I am new here and I need help on how to use terminal and especially how to enter a document using terminal. All I know is:

```
cd ~/Desktop/
```

Can you help me out? Thank you.

Comment: Enter document ? what do you mean ? open document ? write text to document ? read document text ? what kind of document ?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Do you want to know how to read the document? Edit the document? Or...what?

Comment: i have files within a document i want to work with so how can i access the files

Answer (score 2):

There are several commands you need to learn here

`pwd` gives path of your current directory

for example

```
pwd
/home/"username"/Documents
```

If you do `cd ..`

Then you move up one directory

For example here

```
cd ..
pwd
/home/"username"
```

To move to a different directory also you use `cd` command

For example here

```
cd Videos
pwd
/home/"username"/Videos
```

To move up two directories at one go do the following

```
cd ../..
pwd
/home
```

You can also move up two directories at one go

```
cd "username"/Music
pwd
/home/"username"/Music
```

You can also do

```
cd ../Documents
pwd 
/home/"username"/Documents
```

To view the contents of a file you need `ls` command

For example

```
ls
File1.txt  File2.txt  File3.pdf  File4.odt
```

As a starter I would recommend that you use `gedit`

If you are unsure whether you have it or not you can always do

```
sudo apt-get install gedit
```

Then for example to open and edit File1.txt do

```
gedit File1.txt
```

Other solely terminal based editors out there are vi, vim, emacs, nano and so on. But they will be difficult for you to use now

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view a file's contents, you have many options to choose from: cat, head, tail, more, less

[Viewing text files on Linux - cat, head, tail, more and less](https://2buntu.com/articles/1491/viewing-text-files-on-linux-cat-head-tail-more-and-less/) by Nitin Venkatesh

> 1. head <filename> - View the top few lines of a file
>
>    - -<lines> - Displays the first <lines> number of lines of a file
> 2. tail <filename> - View the bottom few lines of a file
>
>    - -<lines> - Displays the last <lines> number of lines of a file
>    - -f : continually watch for any additions at the end of the file
>    - -f --pid=PID - continually display any additions until process with PID terminates
>    - -f -s <sec> - continually display any additions at intervals of <sec>   seconds
> 3. cat <filename> - View the whole file
>
>    - -n : line-numbered output
>    - -b : line-numbered output with no line numbers for blank lines
>    - -s : multiple blank lines compressed into a single blank line
> 4. more <filename> - View the whole file, one screenful at a time.
>
>    - spacebar : View next screen
>    - b : View previous screen
>    - d : View next half-screen
>    - <kbd>Enter</kbd> : View next line
>    - = : Current line number in file
>    - v : Start vi editor on current line
>    - /string : Search for string in file
>
>      - n : Go to next occurrence of string
>      - ' : Go to first occurrence of string
> 5. less <filename> - Same as `more`, but with many more features. Displays the portion of the file without waiting for the entire file to be read by it. Accepts most of the `more` commands.
>
>    - <kbd>Pg Dn</kbd> : View next screen
>    - <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> : View previous screen
>    - Up arrow : View previous line
>    - Down arrow : View next line

Comment: OK, but you really should show examples. Just posting link into answer is considered low quality answer. Also, we don't know exactly what OP wants so next time don't rush to answer a question till you know what is asked. Otherwise, welcome to AskUbuntu !